# Exchanging objects in distinguished triangles

Tags: category-theory, triangulated-categories

Let $\mathcal{D}$ be a triangulated category and assume we are given two distinguished triangles
$$
\begin{align}
A \rightarrow B \rightarrow C \rightarrow +1\\
D \rightarrow C \rightarrow E \rightarrow + 1
\end{align}
$$
does there exist a d.t. 
$$
D \oplus A \rightarrow B \rightarrow E \rightarrow +1$$
where $B \rightarrow E = B \rightarrow C \rightarrow E$?
 The question is motivated by the following: if $\mathcal{D}$ were the homotopy category of complexes of an abelian category, and we had two exact sequences
$$
\begin{align}
0 \rightarrow A \rightarrow B \rightarrow C \rightarrow 0\\
0 \rightarrow D \rightarrow C \rightarrow E \rightarrow 0
\end{align}
$$ then we could regard $C$ as $C \simeq \left[ A \rightarrow B \right]$, with $B$ in degree zero, and therefore the second exact sequence can be considered as
$$
D \rightarrow \left[ A \rightarrow B \right] \rightarrow E \rightarrow +1
$$
i.e.
$$
E = Cone(D \rightarrow \left[A \rightarrow B \right]) = \left[ D \oplus A \rightarrow B \right]$$
which gives what we want. In the case of a general triangulated category, using the following d.t.
$$
\begin{align}
B \rightarrow C \rightarrow A[1] \rightarrow +1\\
C \rightarrow E \rightarrow D[1] \rightarrow +1\\
B \rightarrow E \rightarrow Z \rightarrow +1
\end{align}
$$
and the octahedron axiom, one finds the d.t.
$$
A[1] \rightarrow Z \rightarrow D[1] \rightarrow +1
$$
but how can I show that $Z[-1] \simeq A \oplus D$?